# bybit api cant find data for my token ('VAIUSDT")

Tags: python, cryptography, bybit

```
def get_price_history(symbol, interval):
    session = spot.HTTP(endpoint="https://api.bybit.com")
    kline = session.query_kline(symbol=symbol, interval=interval)
    kline = kline['result']
    df = pd.DataFrame(kline)
    df = df.iloc[:, :6]
    df.columns = ['Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
    df = df.set_index('Time')
    df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, unit='ms')
    df = df.astype(float)
    return df['Close']
```

this function gets data from bybit api
symbol is VAIUSDT VAI is crypto token named vaiot

thats an error:

```
pybit.exceptions.InvalidRequestError: Not supported symbols (ErrCode: -100011) (ErrTime: 19:07:06).
Request → GET https://api.bybit.com/spot/quote/v1/kline: {'symbol': 'VAIUSDT', 'interval': '15m'}.
```

Comment: i think VAIUSDT has not been listed yet in that crypto exchange.

Comment: no its already listed: https://www.bybit.com/en-US/coin-price/vaiot/

Comment: I searched that pair got no result in usdt section.